# I am unable to run "drush site-install" without getting errors

Tags: drush

When I open Terminal on the *david/Sites/animals* directory, and I run `drush site-install --db-url=mysql://david:root@localhost:3306/animals`, the get the following error.

> In SiteInstallCommands.php line 152: Drush was unable to drop all tables because `mysql` was not found, and therefore Drupal threw an AlreadyInstalledException. Ensure `mysql` is available in your PATH.

Did I write the correct command?

Comment: This one helped me a lot back then when I used MAMP: https://www.drupal.org/node/1651282#comment-12366073. But honestly, drop MAMP. Use DDEV, Lando or Docksal instead. I use DDEV. Drush already in there.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is part of the error message. `Ensure mysql is available in your PATH.` The command mysql is included in MAMP. You just need to add it the `PATH` environmental variable.

There are many, many post about this - see for example
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684347/mac-os-x-mamp-how-to-run-mysql-without-having-to-type-in-the-full-path